# using one password for several files

Tags: passwords

I have an application that uses several encrypted files. Because it would not be a good idea to take a password from user for each file, I ended up with a single password.

I wondered about safety of this approach, then I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381980/is-it-secure-to-derive-multiple-keys-from-one-password) that says it can be done. I wanted to know if the answers proposed there are safe? Is there a limit for files that use same password if I use this methods (like different salt)?

Also, is there a better way for doing this (one password for several files)?

Of course, I know that using one password for several file will be less secure than one password for each file.

Comment: If you use a password protected ZIP file or a password protected disk you  implicitly use the same password to protect multiple files. So it is actually common. But usually you don't use the password to encrypt the files but derive a strong key from the password using a key derivation function or use the password to protect random keys which then are used to encrypt the files.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich thanks. can you provide a link (example) for second way (protect random keys) please.

Comment: Many software for disk encryption decouples passphrase from encryption key this way. This makes it possible to change the passphrase or add multiple passphrases without decrypting and re-encrypting the whole disk with the new passphrase again. See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24022/luks-multiple-key-slots-whats-the-intuition.